# What are Ember.Controllers used for?

Tags: ember.js

I'd like some examples please of how you use Ember.Controller objects. Apart from the StateManager, I really don't find myself using Ember.Controllers much at all. In the Ember source code it says that `action`s should be sent to the controller, but I really don't find myself using these so much, because I abstract the views so much, and therefore use the in-built `action`s like `click`, `change`, and `keyUp`. Am I abstracting too much?

For instance, if I'm displaying a button on the page, then I'll create a new Ember.View in my controller view, and then simply include that on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Most direct interaction with controllers is indeed through the `StateManager`/`Router`. The controller's main responsibility is to present data to the views for rendering. They do this by proxying to models as well as maintaining transient state.

You are also correct that a single controller can often be responsible for a hierarchy of views.

I recently did a talk about the responsibilities of various layers in Ember apps. Slides are here: http://www.lukemelia.com/devblog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/

Answer (score 1):

This website has a pretty good presentation of how to use each part of Ember's MVC, and their relationship with each other:

http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/